# Java : Json with duplicate keys to map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have a json file with same key but different values as follows,

```
{
    "domains" : {
        "A" : {
            "name" : "a",
            "type" : "a1"
        },
        "B"  :{
            "name" : "r",
            "type" : "g1"
         },
        "A" : {
           "name" : "b",
           "type" : "b1"
        }
    }
}
```

which is coming from **external system**.
How to convert the **json to java map** object and access the different values of the key: A

I am using something like below,

```
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
```

which returns a map with unique keys. But I need a map object to hold all the data from json file.

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: The results of parsing such JSON are undefined "by definition"; the only way you'll be able to do that with Jackson is to parse it yourself (instantiate a `JsonParser`; and read token by token). First things first however, you should whack the producer of that JSON with a sledgehammer and tell him/her to go read RFC 7159.

Comment: By the way, the relevant text: [RFC 7159, section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4): "When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with comments by @fge.

But if you really insists on solving this, you could sub-class `HashMap` (or any other `Map`), override its `put` method, and handle duplicates using whatever mechanism you want. Just make sure your `Map` has a no-arguments constructor.

Guava may also have a datatype that would allow retaining duplicates (`Multimap`?). If so, you will want to use Jackson's Guava module: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava

Comment: Actually, with Guava there is an even more simple way: use a `ForwardingMap`. Well, that doesn't prevent the fact that the JSON is broken to start with, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Answering since a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425276/how-to-allow-duplicate-keys-when-using-jackson-objectmapper) was marked duplicate but seems to address the reverse problem where JSON with duplicate keys needs to be created. So that is Java Model -> JSON with duplicate keys.

Simplest way I found was to implement a [custom serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

```
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<ModelToSerialize> {


    public CustomSerializer(Class<ModelToSerialize> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ModelToSerialize value, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("DuplicateJsonKey", value.getDup1());
        gen.writeStringField("DuplicateJsonKey", value.getDup2());
        // Map all other values on value that you want to be present in the JSON
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And then when you go to serialize:

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addSerializer(ModelToSerialize.class, new CustomSerializer(ModelToSerialize.class));
objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
String sr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(modelToSerialize);
```